# My database don't work on Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have implemented one database with sqlite on Android but it doesn't work and i don't no why ... Can you help me little ? It's my first time.

When i would add data i have this error :

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table table_GAME has no column named _id_game

My code :

```
    public class BaseSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION_BDD = 1;
    private static final String NOM_BDD = "games.db";

    private static final String TABLE_GAME = "table_GAME";
    private static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COL_ID_GAME = "_id_game";
    private static final String COL_NB_JOUEURS = "Nb_joueurs";
    private static final String COL_ID_TOUR = "Numéro_du_tour";
    private static final String COL_PRENEUR = "Preneur";
    private static final String COL_CONTRAT = "Contrats";
    private static final String COL_BOUTS = "Bouts";
    private static final String COL_PETIT = "Petit";
    private static final String COL_21 = "vingt_un";
    private static final String COL_ESXCUSE = "Escuse";
    private static final String COL_POINTS = "Points";
    private static final String COL_JOUEUR_APPELE = "Joueurs_appele";
    private static final String COL_JOUEUR_1 ="j1";
    private static final String COL_JOUEUR_2="j2";
    private static final String COL_JOUEUR_3="j3";
    private static final String COL_JOUEUR_4="j4";
    private static final String COL_JOUEUR_5="j5";

    private static final String TABLE_JOUEURS ="table_JOUEURS";
    private static final String COL_ID_JOUEURS ="id_du_joueur";
    private static final String COL_NOMS_JOUEURS ="nom_du_joueur";

    private static final String Table1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GAME + " ("+
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COL_ID_GAME +" INTEGER, "
            + COL_NB_JOUEURS +" INTEGER, "
            + COL_ID_TOUR + " INTEGER, "
            + COL_PRENEUR + " INTEGER, "
            + COL_CONTRAT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_BOUTS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_PETIT+ " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_21+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_ESXCUSE+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_POINTS+" INTEGER, "
            + COL_JOUEUR_APPELE +" INTEGER, "
            + COL_JOUEUR_1+" INTEGER, "
            + COL_JOUEUR_2+" INTEGER, "
            + COL_JOUEUR_3+" INTEGER, "
            + COL_JOUEUR_4+" INTEGER, "
            + COL_JOUEUR_5+" INTEGER "+");";

    private static final String Table2 ="CREATE TABLE '"+ TABLE_JOUEURS +"' ('" +
            COL_ID_JOUEURS+"' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '"
            + COL_NOMS_JOUEURS+ "' TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public BaseSQL(Context context) {
        super(context, NOM_BDD, null, VERSION_BDD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Table1);
        db.execSQL(Table2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(BaseSQL.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_GAME + ";");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_JOUEURS + ";");

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: once reinstall your application

Comment: @RRR I have already reinstall my application :(

Comment: Set VERSION_BDD = 2 and reinstall the application